# Sound Anomaly Detection

Tags: keras, cnn, anomaly-detection

What is the recommended directory structure for sound anomaly detection using Keras CNN (Unsupervised) ?
After converting the sound files into spectrograms. Code examples will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Anomaly Detection for sound has been researched actively in the last years. One of the leading venues is the [DCASE community](https://dcase.community/). Since 2019 it has hosted a challenge on the task called *Unsupervised Detection of Anomalous Sounds*, which is based on an open dataset.

The results are described as technical reports describing the proposed methods, and there have been some 20-30 papers each year:

- [DCASE2022 Task 2 results](https://dcase.community/challenge2021/task-unsupervised-detection-of-anomalous-sounds-results)
- [DCASE2021 Task 2 results](https://dcase.community/challenge2022/task-unsupervised-anomalous-sound-detection-for-machine-condition-monitoring-results)
- [DCASE2022 Task 2 results](https://dcase.community/challenge2020/task-unsupervised-detection-of-anomalous-sounds-results)

There are also a set of reference implementations. These are a good starting point for building your own solution.

- [DCASE2022 baseline using AutoEncoder](https://github.com/Kota-Dohi/dcase2022_task2_baseline_ae)
- [DCASE2022 baseline using MobileNet](https://github.com/Kota-Dohi/dcase2022_task2_baseline_mobile_net_v2)